# Reverse .wav file in C, any error in there?

Tags: c, reverse, cs50, wav

I've been making the program from CS50'x about reversing the .WAV files. Seems to work fine, however the cs50's check finds an error. Don't know where it is, the code seems to be alright and there I can't find any problem.

I tried to change 'i' - iterator in for-loop but when set as = infile_size - block_size the file won't be converted / reversed.
My code below:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "wav.h"

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    // check if command-line arguments = argv[0], argv[1], argv[2] = 3 in sum
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        if (argc < 3)
        {
            printf("not enough command-line args\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("too much command-line args\n");
        }
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile = argv[2];

    // open input file for reading
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open the infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // read header into an array
    WAVHEADER header;
    fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, inptr);

    // use check_format to ensure WAV format
    check_format(header);

    // open output file for writing
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't open the outfile\n");
        fclose(inptr);
        return 1;
    }

    // write header to file
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, outptr);

    // use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    int block_size = get_block_size(header);
    printf("block_size: %i\n", block_size);
    if (block_size < 0)
    {
        printf("block_size with no size\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // write reversed audio to file
    // 1. declare an array to store each block of audio
    char *buffer = malloc(block_size * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("no memory location");
        return 1;
    }

    // get the size of the input file
    fseek(inptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int infile_size = ftell(inptr);
    printf("file_size: %li\n", infile_size);

    // iterate through the input file audio data
    for (long int i = infile_size; i >= 0; i -= block_size)
    {
        // move the file indicator to the start
        fseek(inptr, i, SEEK_SET);

        // read from inptr each size
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), block_size, inptr);

        // write in outfile
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), block_size, outptr);
    }

    // free
    free(buffer);

    // close files:
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);
}

int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4
    if (header.format[0] == 'W' && header.format[1] == 'A' && header.format[2] == 'V' && header.format[3] == 'E')
    {
        printf("This is the type .wav\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File is not the type .wav\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #7
    // check if channels are mono or audio
    if (header.numChannels == 1 || header.numChannels == 2)
    {
        int block_size;
        block_size = header.numChannels * (header.bitsPerSample / 8);
        return block_size;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not supported\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must explicitly open the files in binary mode: `"rb"` and `"wb"`.

Comment: If you look at the first iteration of the reversal loop can you see that `fseek(inptr, i, SEEK_SET);` will seek to the wrong place (you can't read data from the end of a file)? And will iterate once too many? Try `for (long int i = infile_size - block_size; i >= 0; i -= block_size)`. If you make a habit of always checking the return value from `fread` (number of items read) this would have informed you.

Comment: Thanks man, didn't notice that binary mode is necessary and the block_size has to be decremented twice in for_loop. However, when I do the step in for-loop it includes my header at the end of the file...

Comment: It *doesn't* have to decrement twice. It needs to start at the last element in the file. This is similar to array indexing. the last element of an array with `n` elements is at `[n - 1]`. The last data in your file is at position `file_size - block-size`. There is no data at position `file_size`. You should have noticed that the output file was bigger than the input file.

Comment: So, should I change the size of file?

Comment: Have you followed these comments? You have read one data point too many, with an attempt that would cause a read error. Always check that `fread` did what it was supposed to.

Comment: Completely. Integer in loop is [n - 1] so fread works fine. But the cs50's check tells me now the reversed header is included at the end of file. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251790/discussion-between-juri-and-weather-vane).

Comment: I see, then you need to end the loop sooner. `for (long int i = infile_size - block_size; i >= sizeof(header); i -= block_size)`.

Comment: ... but I find it strange that your deleted comment said the file was 4 bytes too big. That didn't include the header written twice, just the fictional data point.

Comment: the outfille was 44 bytes bigger (I guess it includes this reversed header at the end)